# How to select first coordinates in multipoint or in collection used for point reducing?

Tags: postgis, point

I am using PostGis and I have geometry like this:

```
MULTIPOINT(1673118.56314624 5778263.30559826,1672914.41092247 
5778129.131443,1672384.7731665 5778105.44570288,1673513.70724225
5778525.74090022)
```

OR collection:

```
GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(POINT(1673118.56314624 5778263.30559826),
POINT(1672914.41092247 5778129.131443),POINT(1672384.7731665 5778105.44570288),
POINT(1673513.70724225 5778525.74090022))
```

I get it like this for collection:

```
SELECT st_astext(unnest(ST_ClusterWithin(geom, 700)))
gc FROM table
```

or like this to get multipoints

```
SELECT st_astext(ST_CollectionExtract(unnest(ST_ClusterWithin(geom, 700)) , 1))
gc FROM towersnew
```

And I would like to to transform it to point where the only coordinates are first coordinates (others are omitted). Result is supposed to be:

```
POINT(1673118.56314624 5778263.30559826)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ST_Dump will do it....  change DESC to ASC to get the other end.

This example sorts the geometry by ST_Y:

```
SELECT ST_Astext(geom)
FROM ST_Dump('MULTIPOINT(1673118.56314624 5778263.30559826,1672914.41092247 5778129.131443,1672384.7731665 5778105.44570288,1673513.70724225 5778525.74090022)')
Order By ST_Y(geom) DESC
Limit 1
```

Or this example filters by path #:

```
SELECT ST_Astext(geom)
FROM ST_Dump('MULTIPOINT(1673118.56314624 5778263.30559826,1672914.41092247 5778129.131443,1672384.7731665 5778105.44570288,1673513.70724225 5778525.74090022)')
WHERE path ='{1}'
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I managed to make it work but I got some errors while processing data. The other solution works fine for me!

Comment: How to solve it when I get results FROM query: SELECT (ST_CollectionExtract(unnest(ST_ClusterWithin(geom, 700)), 1)) as gc FROM data Now I have multiple sets and I have to get first point from each row?

Comment: Deleted the other answer as i realized my mistake. I mixed first point and xmin when i wrote it. And Postgis does not have first point for other than linestring geometries. So this seems to be the way to go. But you need the path {1,1] for polygons. And geometry collections need to be extracted first.

Comment: Thanks I solved it: SELECT st_astext((m.geom).geom) FROM (SELECT st_dump(ST_CollectionExtract(unnest(ST_ClusterWithin(geom, 700)), 1)) AS geom
               FROM data ) m WHERE (geom).path='{1}';

Comment: @M.V. you can also try using the LIMIT keyword to limit your results.

Answer (score 3):

[`ST_GeometryN(Geometry, n)`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeometryN.html) seems to be a nicer way to extract `POINT` *n* from a `MULTIPOINT` list.

*Apologies for the boilerplate* but here is an example where I take the second element!

```
 SELECT ST_AsText(
           ST_GeometryN(
              ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOINT(11 11, 22 22,33 33)'),
              2 
           )
        );


 st_astext   
--------------
 POINT(22 22)
(1 row)
```